# Mongoid parsing and storing a date

Tags: ruby, mongodb, date, mongoid

I am receiving dates from a web form that come in format of "Thursday, November 8th". I want to ensure that I store this in MongoDB (I'm using Mongoid as my client driver) in an appropriate Date field. Using Ruby or any available type library, what's the best way to ensure when I'm parsing this date that I store it in a way that won't break the Date field Mongoid/MongoDB support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Time.parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) (from the Ruby Standard Library) to convert the string which comes from the web form into a Time object, e.g.:

```
time = Time.parse(params[:date])
```

Since this is provided by the Ruby Standard Library, so you may need to prepend a `require "time"` to this statement.